# Consistency of sample quantile to population quantile for discrete variables

Tags: probability-or-statistics, order

Can I know if the sample quantile converges to the population quantile in probability for discrete variables?

If we use Hoeffding (1963)'s results, is this true?

Comment: you might want to try the stackexchange site [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) for your mathematical statistics questions.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this belongs on [stats.SE]